# How to open ActionMode menu with help of Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to test the scenario like below.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    @Test
    public void testRenameList() {
        addNewList();

        // Long click on the list
        onView(recyclerViewItemWithText(mNewListName)).perform(longClick());

        openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
    }
```

The following error occures on the last line: 
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '((is displayed on the screen to the user and with content description: is "More options") or (is displayed on the screen to the user and with class name: a string ending with "OverflowMenuButton"))' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

I think, Espresso finds two menu: from ActionMode and from ActionBar.

The question is how to open menu exactly from ActionMode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using UIAutomator.
I've replaced the line

```
openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
```

by

```
UiObject btnMenu = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().description(mActivity.getString(R.string.menu_button_identifier)));
btnMenu.click();
```

The value of R.string.menu_button_identifier in English is "More options".

Comment: Which R did you include? I cannot find the resource menu_button_identifier in android.R